# How to fetch the results from one if condition to another in java which parses xml document

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have two tables in xml document tree linked with each other. Code is:

```
<table name="categoryConfigTable">
    <row>
        <field name="mediaConfigId">0</field>
        <field name="startDate">2005-01-01</field>
        <field name="endDate">2025-12-31</field>
        <field name="class">all</field>
        <field name="CID">10</field>
        <field name="sequenceNum">1</field>
        <field name="parentCID">NULL</field>
    </row>
</table>  

<table name="categoryInfoTable">
    <row>
        <field name="CID">7</field>
        <field name="LID">1</field>
        <field name="title">Misc</field>
        <field name="description"/>
        <field name="shortDescription"/>
        <field name="synopsisImgID">0</field>
        <field name="posterImgID">0</field>
    </row>
</table>
```

From Categoryconfig i fetched those CID values whose parentCID is NULL.
Now i want to use these fetched CID values in CategoryInfo table to get Titles related to that CID. How this can be done????

My Java code is:

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {
        File fXmlFile = new File("/home/vaishali/vaishalik/media.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element :"+ doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("table");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        String cidvalue = null;
        String titlevalue=null;

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                if(eElement.getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase("categoryConfigTable"))
                {
                     NodeList nList2 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("field");
                     for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < nList2.getLength(); temp1++) {
                         Node nNode1 = nList2.item(temp1);
                         if (nNode1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                             Element eElement1 = (Element) nNode1;
                             if(eElement1.getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase("CID"))
                             {
                                cidvalue=eElement1.getTextContent();
                             }
                             if(eElement1.getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase("parentCID") && (eElement1.getTextContent().equalsIgnoreCase("NULL")))
                             {
                                 System.out.println(" where parentCID is NULL, corresponding CID value :: "+cidvalue);
                             }
                         }
                     }
                }

                if(eElement.getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase("categoryInfoTable"))
                {
                     NodeList nList2 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("field");
                     for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < nList2.getLength(); temp1++) {
                         Node nNode1 = nList2.item(temp1);
                         if (nNode1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                             Element eElement1 = (Element) nNode1;
                             if(eElement1.getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
                             {
                                titlevalue=eElement1.getTextContent();
                             }
                             if(eElement1.getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase("CID") && (eElement1.getTextContent().equalsIgnoreCase(cidvalue)))
                             {
                                 System.out.println(" Title value :: "+titlevalue);

                             }
                         }
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pls help me out in this

Comment: can anyone solve this query